# How to handle webservice Exception return to client (SocketTimeoutException)?

Tags: java, xml, apache, web-services, soap

I am new to develop cxf webservice, and I am testing this by SOAP-UI. but i have got some question for WS call socket.

Here is my code:

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://ws.profep.com/", portName = "GpmsGWPort", serviceName = "GpmsGWService")
public class GpmsGW {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(GpmsGW.class);
    Properties prop = new Properties();

    public GpmsGW() {
        super();
        log.debug("--GpmsGW was Init--");
    }

    private boolean loadConfig(){
        try{
            InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ConConfig.properties");
            prop.load(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));

            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.error("", e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public MsgRs sendMsg(MsgRq msgRq){
        log.debug("--MESSAGE POST--");
        loadConfig();
        MsgRs msgRs = new MsgRs();
        Socket socketIn = null, socketOut = null;
        DataInputStream dis;
        DataOutputStream dos;

        try{
            socketIn = new Socket(prop.getProperty("rIp"), Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("rPort")));
            socketOut = new Socket(prop.getProperty("sIp"), Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("sPort")));
            int timeout = 60000;
            socketIn.setSoTimeout(timeout);
            socketOut.setSoTimeout(timeout);

            dis = new DataInputStream(socketIn.getInputStream());
            dos = new DataOutputStream(socketOut.getOutputStream());
//          String request = renderRequest(msgRq) ;
            String request = testReq(msgRq) ; //測試用
            byte[] reqmsg = Utility.hexStr2Bytes(Utility.stringToHex(request));
            dos.write(Utility.addHeaderLLLL(reqmsg));
            dos.flush();

            byte[] inLen = new byte[4];
            dis.read(inLen, 0, 4);
            byte[] res = new byte[Integer.parseInt(new String(inLen))];
            dis.readFully(res);
            String response = new String(res);
            log.info("WS Response=[" + response + "]"); 
            msgRs = parseResponse(response);
        }
        catch(SocketTimeoutException se){
            log.error("WS socket is timeout!!!");
            return genTimeoutResponse(msgRq);
        }
        catch(Exception e2){
            log.error("", e2);
            try {
                if(socketIn != null){socketIn.close();}
                if(socketOut != null){socketOut.close();}
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error("Exception occurred : " + e);
            }
        }

        return msgRs;
    }
```

Question: however if the `SockeTimeoutException` occured, and Tomcat log got exception, soapUI got no response message.. how can I handle Exception and return correct xml response in my code??

```
Message: Outbound Message
---------------------------
ID: 4
Response-Code: 200
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {}
Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns2:sendMsgResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.profep.com/"><return/></ns2:sendMsgResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
--------------------------------------
May 24, 2016 11:06:29 上午 org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
Warring: Interceptor for {http://ws.profep.com/}GpmsGWService#{http://ws.profep.com/}sendMsg has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor.handleMessage(OutgoingChainInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:181)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:289)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:209)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:367)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.flushBuffer(Response.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.flushBuffer(ResponseFacade.java:306)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$WrappedOutputStream.close(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:763)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:223)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$BackChannelConduit.close(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:692)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:215)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:480)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.flush(InternalOutputBuffer.java:119)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:363)
    ... 42 more

五月 24, 2016 11:06:29 上午 org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
警告: Interceptor for {http://ws.profep.com/}GpmsGWService#{http://ws.profep.com/}sendMsg has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Error writing to XMLStreamWriter.
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor$SoapOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapOutInterceptor.java:314)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor$SoapOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapOutInterceptor.java:291)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:336)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor.handleMessage(OutgoingChainInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:181)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:289)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:209)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: No open start element, when trying to write end element
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.throwOutputError(BaseStreamWriter.java:1537)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.reportNwfStructure(BaseStreamWriter.java:1566)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseNsStreamWriter.doWriteEndTag(BaseNsStreamWriter.java:648)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseNsStreamWriter.writeEndElement(BaseNsStreamWriter.java:280)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor$SoapOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapOutInterceptor.java:301)
    ... 36 more
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I just solve my question by other way..
cause soap is my transfer format..
I can thorow saop fault(Exception) to client
The fallowing is my code..

```
    public MsgRs sendMsg(MsgRq msgRq) throws CustomException{
        log.debug("--MESSAGE POST--");
        loadConfig();
        MsgRs msgRs = new MsgRs();
        Socket socketIn = null, socketOut = null;
        DataInputStream dis;
        DataOutputStream dos;

        try{
            socketIn = new Socket(prop.getProperty("rIp"), Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("rPort")));
            socketOut = new Socket(prop.getProperty("sIp"), Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("sPort")));
            int timeout = 30000;
            socketIn.setSoTimeout(timeout);
            socketOut.setSoTimeout(timeout);

            dis = new DataInputStream(socketIn.getInputStream());
            dos = new DataOutputStream(socketOut.getOutputStream());
//          String request = renderRequest(msgRq) ;
            String request = testReq(msgRq) ; //測試用
            byte[] reqmsg = Utility.hexStr2Bytes(Utility.stringToHex(request));
            dos.write(Utility.addHeaderLLLL(reqmsg));
            dos.flush();

            byte[] inLen = new byte[4];
            dis.read(inLen, 0, 4);
            byte[] res = new byte[Integer.parseInt(new String(inLen))];
            dis.readFully(res);
            String response = new String(res);
            log.info("WS Response=[" + response + "]"); 
            msgRs = parseResponse(response);
        }
        catch(SocketTimeoutException se){
            log.error("WS socket is timeout!!!");
//          msgRs = genTimeoutResponse(msgRq);
            throw new CustomException("socket is timeout.");
        }
        catch(Exception e2){
            log.error("", e2);
            try {
                if(socketIn != null){socketIn.close();}
                if(socketOut != null){socketOut.close();}
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error("Exception occurred : " + e);
            }
            throw new CustomException("Exception occurred : " + e2);
        }

        return msgRs;
    }

    @WebFault(name="CustomException")
    public class CustomException extends Exception{
        public CustomException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }
```

then I just test by SOAP-UI ..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iX9P.jpg)

its no exception occurd and get correspond response message.